# How to write a MySQL sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Raw data in mysql table is:

```
APP  EVENT
app1 clk
app1 req
app2 clk
app1 imp
app2 req
```

Now, I want to get the following result, to statistic count of event per app

```
APP clk imp req
app1 1  1   1
app2 1  0   1
```

How to write a sql query to achieve that?

Comment: This involves pivoting, a faq, which you would find if you googled many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question/problem/goal/issue. Please also read hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: what did you research or try so far? We're happy to help you with your attempt to solve your problem, if you've made one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the APP and then use conditional counting for EVENT.

```
SELECT
APP,
COUNT(CASE WHEN EVENT = 'clk' THEN 1 END) AS clk,
COUNT(CASE WHEN EVENT = 'imp' THEN 1 END) AS imp,
COUNT(CASE WHEN EVENT = 'req' THEN 1 END) AS req
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY APP
ORDER BY APP;
```

SQL Fiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3f4ae/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has shorthand for conditional aggregation, so you can do :

```
select app, 
       sum(EVENT = 'clk') as clk,
       sum(EVENT = 'imp') as imp,
       sum(EVENT = 'req') as req
from table t
group by app;
```

This [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f0e4e/1) shows that it's working

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *Aggregate function condition*

```
SELECT APP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EVENT ='clk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) clk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EVENT ='imp' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) imp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EVENT ='req' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) req
FROM T
GROUP BY APP
```